# Accept string using scanf and display them using printf

Tags: c

I cannot retrieve string using printf . instead getting error : segmentation fault

```
int main(){

        char * a[5];
        int i;

        printf("\n enter value ");

        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
                printf("%d Name :\n",i);
                scanf("%s",&a[i]);
        }

        printf("%s",a[2]);
        printf("%s",a[3]);

}
~
```

Comment: You have an array of pointers and do not allocate any memore for them. Accessing memory via unitialized pointers is undefined behaviour and may result in seg fault.

Comment: Do you want to enter and print 5 names, or enter and print 1 name with 5 characters?  Start with always allowing room for a NULL character in your string (char array), allocate it using a[6] instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

`char * a[5];` is `array of 5 char pointer` that means you can store 5 char buffer of any length.
The problem is in the  statement 
`scanf("%s",&a[i]);` replace this with `scanf("%s",a[i]);`

**case 1** :-

```
int main(){
        char *a[5] = {"stackoverflow","meta","ask ubuntu","super","unix"};
        /* here a[row] can have any number of char */
        for (int i = 0 ;i < 5;i++) {
                printf("%s\n",a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**Case 2** :-

```
int main(){
        char *a[5];
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            printf("%d Name :\n",i);
            a[i] = malloc(MAX);/* define MAX how many char you want to store into that */
            scanf("%s",a[i]); /* & not required as a[i] itself address */
        }
        for (int i = 0 ;i < 5;i++) {
                printf("%s\n",a[i]);
        }
        /* don't forget to free once job is done */
        for (int i = 0 ;i < 5;i++) {
                free(a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a pointer before it has been initialized. It does not yet point at valid memory. These leads to program crashes or other kinds of unexpected behavior, such as "segmentation faults".

So you should edit it to:

```
char* my_string = malloc(size+1);
```

---

The `%c` format specifier is used whenever we want to be specific that the variable that we are going to `printf` or `scanf` is of type `char`.

On the other hand the `%s` format specifier is used to specify to the `printf` or `scanf` functions that contents of the address that is specified as the next parameter are to considered as `string`.

You are taking `char` as input, not the whole `string`.

`scanf("%s",&a[i]);`, will be `scanf("%c",&a[i]);`
`printf("%s",a[3]);`,  will be `printf("%c",a[3]);`
`printf("%s",a[2]);`, will be `printf("%c",a[2]);`

The following code worked fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

        char* a = malloc(size+1); // where size is max string length
        int i;

        printf("\n enter value ");

        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
                printf("%d Name :\n",i);
                scanf("%c",&a[i]);
                printf("%c\n",a[i]);
        }

        printf("%c\n",a[2]);
        printf("%c\n",a[3]);
        free(a);
}
```

Comment: "worked perfectly fine" is one of many results of undefined behavior. You really shouldn't teach beginners to store 1 char in one of the bytes of a pointer, then print it as if it was the correct thing to do. The OP obviously don't have a clue how to use pointers or strings in the first place, so this isn't helping.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will edit it as one of the methods and wite some basics of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hmm. You _have_ noticed that the OP used a `char*` array and not a `char` array, right?

Comment: Yeah, I am editing the post regarding that only.

Comment: is it okay now? or still i am missing something?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post and add the malloc call you proposed to the snippet at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for that, that way it's better

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** input to a `char*` .
And you shouldn't store any string by `char*`, including `string literal`, in fact, `string literal` convert to `char*` is deprecated many years ago.
Use `char a[5][MaximumLength]` instead. `MaximumLength` should be a *literal*.